# Having trouble with the the turtle module to draw the Spiral of Theodorus

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

One of the problems for my programming assignment is to use the turtle module to draw the [Spiral of Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus)! with 
n = 17.

I've got all the code done but whenever it the scale of the drawing is super off. For example in the first triangle with the dimensions sqrt(1), 1, sqrt(2) the triangle would be a 45, 45 triangle, but in turtle 1 = 1 pixel and that would illegible so i would have to use a larger number such as 100, but if i use 100 then the dimensions for the 1st triangle would be sqrt(100), 100, sqrt(200). which is not the same triangle proportionally.

Here's my code:

```
def TheodorusSpiral(myTurtle,n,d):
    import math
    myTurtle=turtle
    myTurtle.pu()
    myTurtle.home()
    myTurtle.pd()
    myTurtle.fd(d)
    myTurtle.lt(90)
    myTurtle.fd(d)
    myTurtle.lt(45)
    for i in range(n-1):
        a = (i+2)*d
        c = math.fabs(d*math.sqrt(a))
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(c/d))
        angle2 = math.degrees(math.atan(d/d*math.sqrt(a+1)))
        angle3 = math.degrees(math.atan(d*math.sqrt(a+1)/d))
        angle4 = 180 - (angle2 + angle3)
        angle5 = 180 -(angle + angle4)
        myTurtle.fd(d)
        myTurtle.lt(angle5)



TheodorusSpiral(1,4,50)
```

Also another problem i have is that when i call the function, for the parameter "myTurtle" i can't call it with a name/letter such as "tim".

For example TheodorusSpiral(tim,4,50) would give me the error

> " tim is not defined"

Comment: In your example with a side of 100, the 1st triangle's dimensions shouldn't be sqrt(100), 100, sqrt(200). Instead, they should be 100*sqrt(1), 100*1, 100*sqrt(2). Your error isn't so much a programming error as a math error.

Comment: ok i added the "*d" to the places where i needed to multiply the sqrt and i still get a disproportionate image.

Comment: Your `angle2` and `angle3` calculations look ... strange now. `d/d` is going to cancel out of each one, and you'll always be left with `math.atan(math.sqrt(a+1))`. I think you need to draw yourself a diagram and double-check your math again. Also, better names than `angle2`, `angle3`, etc., might help you avoid mistakes like that in the future. Ask yourself: what is `angle2`? It's the angle between *what* and *what*? Then give it a name that will help you remember what it is.

Comment: Another tip: you can do all your angle calculations as if this was a spiral with sides equal to 1, as in the Wikipedia article's diagram. Then when you scale the diagram up, you'd advance by "d", instead of by "1" -- *but the angles will all be the same*! So that should simplify your angle math.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that when you're doing your angle calculations, you pretend that you're drawing a diagram with the leg length equal to 1, just as in the Wikipedia diagram. So you wouldn't have `d` in your angle calculations at all, like so:

```
import turtle
def TheodorusSpiral(myTurtle,n,d):
    import math
    myTurtle=turtle
    myTurtle.pu()
    myTurtle.home()
    myTurtle.pd()
    myTurtle.fd(d)
    myTurtle.lt(90)
    myTurtle.fd(d)
    myTurtle.lt(45)
    for i in range(n-1):
        a = (i+2)
        c = math.fabs(math.sqrt(a))
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan(c/1))
        angle2 = math.degrees(math.atan(1/math.sqrt(a+1)))
        angle3 = math.degrees(math.atan(math.sqrt(a+1)/1))
        angle4 = 180 - (angle2 + angle3)
        angle5 = 180 -(angle + angle4)
        myTurtle.fd(d)
        myTurtle.lt(angle5)

TheodorusSpiral(1,4,50)
```

Besides the change to your angle calculations (where I basically removed `d` entirely from the math, making it work), I also included the "import turtle" line in the example code, so that the above can be copied and pasted and will run correctly.

As for your other problem, which is that you're trying to call `TheodorusSpiral(tim,4,50)` and it's failing -- there's a fundamental misunderstanding you're having about how Python variables work. You mentioned that this is for an assignment -- I strongly suggest you ask your teacher that question, because you need a more thorough explanation than I have time for. (Sorry). Show your teacher what you're trying to do, and ask him/her to explain to you why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks! I actually fixed my code, i had the wrong idea for what i actually had to draw so that part is all good! Now with the other problem, i did ask my teacher but he said "think about it". I did some research and i came across something about duck typing, but i'm not entirely sure what that means.

Comment: @jimmyle - The resources you've found about duck typing are unrelated to your problem. Here's a hint: when you call `TheodorusSpiral(tim,4,50)`, what do you expect to happen? And if the program is complaining that `tim is not defined`, why might it be expecting the name `tim` to be already defined at that point?

Comment: Do the "think like a computer" exercise -- go through each step, and write down what variables have been created and which ones are being *referenced but not created*. E.g., in `a = (i+2)`, the variable `a` is being created, but `i` is being referenced (and thus should have been created earlier -- which it is, in the `for i in range(n-1)` statement). Now, what about the variable named `tim`? Are you creating it? Or are you referencing it? And if you're only referencing it, where is it being created?

Comment: I'm referencing it, so it needs to have been created/defined prior to calling the function. I could assign it something but i don't know what they would call the function with, for example they could call it with "bob" or "jack" instead, so i can't do that. Then i could make a class? Thanks for being patient with me, this is an intro class and i'm still learning, by making mistakes!